# Javascript .innerHTML fuction output only flashes

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a JS code to find if a string is palindrome or not. But the output only stays on for less than a second then disappears.
I know this type of question has been asked before and I tried the solution which said to add "return false" but its not working for me.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var str1 = str.split("");
  var str2 = str1.reverse();
  var str3 = str2.join("");
  return str3;
}

function checkpalin() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pform").value;
  var st = palindrome(x);
  var flag = st.localeCompare(x);
  if (flag === 0)
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Given number  is a palindrome";
  else
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Not palindrome";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Please enter a string:<br>
  <input type="text" name="str" id="pform" onchange="return checkpalin()"><br>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: If you use `oninput` instead, it'll update while typing.

Comment: Some sort of postback must be happening on the page. Remove the form and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have it in a form. Try this

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var str1 = str.split("");
  var str2 = str1.reverse();
  var str3 = str2.join("");
  return str3;
}

function checkpalin() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pform").value;
  var st = palindrome(x);
  var flag = st.localeCompare(x);
  if (flag === 0)
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Given number  is a palindrome";
  else
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Not palindrome";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    Please enter a string:<br>
    <input type="text" name="str" id="pform" onchange="return checkpalin()"><br>
  <p id="demo"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

You can also use `oninput` instead of `onchange` to make it update while you are typing in the textbox.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var str1 = str.split("");
  var str2 = str1.reverse();
  var str3 = str2.join("");
  return str3;
}

function checkpalin() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pform").value;
  var st = palindrome(x);
  var flag = st.localeCompare(x);
  if (flag === 0)
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Given number  is a palindrome";
  else
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Not palindrome";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    Please enter a string:<br>
    <input type="text" name="str" id="pform" oninput="return checkpalin()"><br>
  <p id="demo"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example given by the OP works just fine without changing anything

Comment: @luca It submits the form

Comment: @Luca He means it shouldn't update on enter key press

Answer (score 1):

The default event when hitting enter in a single field in a form is to submit the form.

In your code the return is only interesting on the submit event.

Just preventDefault on the submit or remove the form tags

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var str1 = str.split("");
  var str2 = str1.reverse();
  var str3 = str2.join("");
  return str3;
}

document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("pform").value;
  var st = palindrome(x);
  var flag = st.localeCompare(x);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = flag ? "Not palindrome" : "Given string  is a palindrome";

}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Please enter a string and hit enter:<br>
  <input type="text" name="str" id="pform"><br>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```